# Filling sparse matrix in Eigen is very slow

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have this code which calls a c++ method in java in a for loop:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_CoreC_MMload(JNIEnv *env3, jobject clazz3, jdoubleArray inputv, jintArray inputi, jint poc, jint pozic)
{
    jdouble* fltv2 ;
    jint* fltind2;
    jsize sizedat = env3->GetArrayLength(inputi);
    fltv2  = new jdouble[sizedat];
    fltind2  = new jint[sizedat];
    jint i;
    jint jm;
    env3->GetIntArrayRegion(inputi,0,sizedat,fltind2);
    env3->GetDoubleArrayRegion(inputv,0,sizedat,fltv2);

    // default is column major
    matA.reserve(VectorXi::Constant(1,sizedat));

    for ( jm = 0; jm < sizedat; jm++) {
        //matA.insert(fltind2[jm],pozic) = fltv2[jm]; // alternative: mat.coeffRef(i,j) += v_ij;
        matA.insert(fltind2[jm],pozic)= fltv2[jm];
        //matA.insertBack(fltind2[jm],pozic)= fltv2[jm];
        //matA.ins
        //matA.insertBackUncompressed();
        //matA.coeffRef(fltind2[jm],pozic) += fltv2[jm];
        // optional
    }

    matA.makeCompressed();

    //k++; //blbe zayklenji!!!
    env3->SetIntArrayRegion(inputi,0,sizedat,fltind2);
    env3->SetDoubleArrayRegion(inputv,0,sizedat,fltv2);
    delete[] fltv2;
    delete[] fltind2;
}
```

Where inputv are values of columns of matA.; and inputi are indexes of these values.

I read in the docs for eigen that the insert function is the fastest, and it's ok when the number of non-zero coefficients are about 5000. But when I have 25000 it takes 5 sec per column!

I tried insrtback, but the values are the same? What exactly does this command do? Is there some way to improve this code?

Once advantage (maybe): the values and indexes in every column are sorted by the values from highest to lowest...

Comment: Do you call this function with increasing pozic values, or with a random pattern? Also if the value are sorted "from highest to lowest", then reverse your loop such that the insert command boils down to simple push-back. The reserve command is not correct.

Comment: 1. yes with increasing; the pozic is from 0 to sizeof columns of matA.; the next you mean that reserve com. take from this method to initialize metho.-of matA.????or whats the coorect way ow write reserve command??

Comment: then the fastest is to call reserve(sizedat); matA.startVec(pozic); for(...) mat.insertBack(fltind2[jm],pozic) = ...; making sure that fltind2[jm] are in increasing order.

Comment: so i just only sort the values by indexes.

Comment: the insetback command, fill martix with zeros ,no with values.

Answer (score 4):

If your sparse matrix is large, you have to allocate sufficient space for matA before filling it. Otherwise, it will take long long time to allocate space and copy data over and over again.

The first thing you need to do is to know the sparsity pattern of your matrix. What I mean by sparsity pattern is the number of non-zeros elements of each column (assume your sparse matrix is in column major). If we store those values in the variable V of type `VectorXi`, calling `matA.reserve(V)` is to allocate sufficient memory space.

Following the above procedure, I am able to fill a 47236x677399 sparse matrix (#non-zeros:49556258) within 30 seconds using an ordinary laptop. If I didn't do so, it takes forever...

Answer (score 2):

Important points from [Eigen Sparse Matrix Tutorial](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html):

```
1: SparseMatrix<double> mat(rows,cols);         // default is column major
2: mat.reserve(VectorXi::Constant(cols,x));
3: for each i,j such that v_ij != 0
4:   mat.insert(i,j) = v_ij;                    // alternative:  mat.coeffRef(i,j) += v_ij;
5: mat.makeCompressed();                        // optional
```

The key ingredient here is line 2 where we reserve room for x non-zeros per column. In many cases, the number of non-zeros per column or row can easily be known in advance. If it varies significantly for each inner vector, then it is possible to specify a reserve size for each inner vector by providing a vector object with an operator[](int j) returning the reserve size of the j-th inner vector (e.g., via a VectorXi or std::vector). If only a rough estimate of the number of nonzeros per inner-vector can be obtained, it is highly recommended to overestimate it rather than the opposite. If this line is omitted, then the first insertion of a new element will reserve room for 2 elements per inner vector.

Line 4 performs a sorted insertion for Column major case. For speed, when filling jth column, existing non-zeros should have row-indices smaller than i. Then, this operation boils down to trivial O(1) operation.

Line 5 suppresses remaining empty space and transforms the matrix into a compressed column storage.